# Filter a large file based on a specific column in bash

Tags: bash

I have a file with >100m lines and wanted to filter it by some criteria:

```
$ wc -l s1bam.bed 
104797540 s1bam.bed

$ head -n 3 s1bam.bed 
chr1    14688   14979   NB501800:50:H3NW5BGX3:2:22310:19560:5036/1  3   +
chr1    14688   14979   NB501800:50:H3NW5BGX3:3:13501:3458:17919/1  3   +
chr1    14727   15018   NB501800:50:H3NW5BGX3:2:22310:19560:5036/2  3   -
```

What I wanted to output is the fifth field value `>=20` and `!=255` (e.g. the second field from right). How to realize it in Bash?

Comment: well explained but essentially no effort shown to solve the main issue... an exact search of question title gives plenty of hints to use `awk`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use awk for this:

```
awk '$5 >= 20 && $5 != 255' file
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava!

Comment: Thank you again! I am wondering whether there is a easy way to tabularize the $5 field and print it out in terminal so that I can choose a good cutoff.

Comment: If you want to print `$5` only for above conditions then use: `awk '$5 >= 20 && $5 != 255{print $5}' file` if you don't want any conditions then just use: `awk '{print $5}' file`